# How can I integrate QC and Perforce

Tags: integration, perforce, hp-quality-center

How can I integrate perforce and HP Quality Center? I would like to link perforce job and HP QC defect, and more important, we want to see perforce changelist in QC.

Answer (score 1):

Perforce supports HP Quality Center with the Defect Tracking Gateway.  It's a free add-on for their customers and fully supported.

https://www.perforce.com/plugins-integrations/defect-tracking-gateway